# Converting System.Drawing.Icon to System.Windows.Controls.Image

Tags: c#, wpf

I want an icon to be displayed in Image control, how can I do that.

```
System.Drawing.Icon icon = System.Drawing.Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(@"C:\Users\bgh32648\Desktop\Filename.extension");

Image Img = new Image();
```

I want to assign icon to img

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public static ImageSource ToImageSource(this Icon icon)
{
    ImageSource imageSource = Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHIcon(
        icon.Handle,
        Int32Rect.Empty,
        BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions());

    return imageSource;
}
```

And then `image.Source = icon.ToImageSource();`

Comment: i tried the solution you gave but it is throwing an error
"Extension method must be defined in a non-generic static class"
    
public  partial  class MainWindow : Window

Comment: Put the extension method in a static class outside of MainWindow

Comment: Using static class ExtensionHelpers fixed the error. Thanks @Snake